# Salesforce Identity URL returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: salesforce

I'm using the [Salesforce.com Identity URL](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&language=en_US) inside my Salesforce Tab to get data about the user who is currently logged in.

The actual URL I use is:

```
https://<INSTANCE_ID>.salesforce.com/id/<ORG_ID>/<USER_ID>
```

With the following HTTP headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
Accept: application/json
```

(I already have `INSTANCE_ID`, so I use it directly instead of `login.salesforce.com` to skip the redirect).

This usually works fine and returns a JSON object with the user data, but in some cases, for specific customers, the response is not a JSON string, but a complete HTML page that says `You Are Now Logged Out.`. The HTTP status code is 200.

I can't find any reference to this problem, can you help me solve it?

Comment: Did you find anything out on this by any chance?

Comment: @r0bb077 only that the problem occurs when using salesforce admin to log in as another user.